# Two ViewModels Binding Using KnockOut JS in a MVC4 View

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am using knockoutJs 3.3.0. In My application I have common javascript file which is reffered all over the application. apart from that I'll be having individual Js files for each page.

So I have two view Models, one is in common and another is page-level viewModel page level one view model. and all the functions of my both Js files are ajax.

I need to bind them in view.

This is my **Common ViewModel**

```
var App = function () {
    var self = {}; 
    self.FP = ko.observable($("#fpTag").val());
    self.UserName = ko.observable($("#StoreValues").val());
    self.Enterprise = ko.observable($("#fpIdentifier").val());
    self.UpdateFP = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/createDeal",
            type: "POST",
            data: { tag: self.FP() },
            success: function (data) {
                self.FpData($.parseJSON(data));
                //return result;
            },
            error: function (data) {
                //return result;
            }
        });
    }
return self;
}
ko.applyBindings(new App());
```

and this is my **PageLevel Js**

```
var Discovery = function() {
var self = {};
var application = new App();
self.KeyWords = ko.observable();
self.GetSearchKeywords = ko.computed(function () {
    var data = application.FpData();
    if (data != null) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetSearchKeywords",
            type: "POST",
            data: { tag: application.UserName(), EnterpriseId: application.Enterprise(), StoreType: "SINGLE", offset: 1 },
            success: function (res) {
                self.KeyWords($.parseJSON(res));
            },
            error: function (res) {
            }
        });
    }
});
return self;};ko.applyBindings(new Discovery());
```

I My view How can I refer the Value as I need all values from both ViewModels.

In My view:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.KeyWords()">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: keyword"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: App().FormatDate(createdOn)"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: ip"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<input data-bind="value: App().FP()"/>
```

How can I achieve this..?

**UPDATE**

Here is the link which I found Helpful. [multiple viewmodels communication](http://www.wrapcode.com/knockoutjs/communication-between-multiple-view-models-in-knockoutjs-mvvm-the-right-approach/)

Comment: Assuming you're bringing the ViewModels to the template/view appropriately, you can utilize `with:` binding. Here's the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is (IMHO) not possible, one can bind only one model to a specific element.

I would try to make one model object a property of the other one.

Comment: I read in one of the articles Double viewModel binding is possible using knockOut JS

Comment: You can bind two models in one HTML page, but not to the same element. The `ko.applyBindings(model)` function binds your model to the whole document. You can use `ko.applyBindings(model, selector)`, e.g. `ko.applyBindings(model1, '#my-div-1')` and `ko.applyBindings(model2, '#my-div-2')` to bind two models, but each to a different part of your document. At least as far as I know.

Anyway, if there is a way to do multiple bindings, I'd gladly learn.

Comment: As far as i know you can't do what you're trying to achieve. If you still have the link for that article, i would be glad to read it. Please post it here.

Comment: As far as I understand the two solutions from the article you linked, they are actually using a master view model, and only this master model is binded to view. The two actual view models (`viewModel1` and `viewModel2`) are in fact properties of the master model.

Answer (score 0):

You should 'composite' the two viewModels together:

**JS:**

```
var App = function (pageVm) {
    var self = {}; 
    if (typeof pageVm !== 'undefined') {
        self.pageVm = pageVm;
    }
    self.FP = ko.observable($("#fpTag").val());
    self.UserName = ko.observable($("#StoreValues").val());
    self.Enterprise = ko.observable($("#fpIdentifier").val());
    self.UpdateFP = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/createDeal",
            type: "POST",
            data: { tag: self.FP() },
            success: function (data) {
                self.FpData($.parseJSON(data));
                //return result;
            },
            error: function (data) {
                //return result;
            }
        });
    }
return self;
}
var pageVm = new Discovery();
ko.applyBindings(new App(pageVm));
```

Now your App bindings work without modification, and you can access your page-specific VMs through the App.pageVm attribute.

I prefer this, typically, rather than binding each VM to a different DOM node (also an option) because often one node may be nested inside the other which can make that difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I found a link to this.. I am sharing that in my update.